# Separating character and numeric variables without delimiter in SAS

Tags: function, sas

I have below data with 5 variables with 5 observations: `Name Age Gender Weight country`

```
data have;
    length string $30.;
    input string$;
    datalines;
Naresh30Male70India
Venkey29Male50Kenya
Ravi30Male56Pak
Sai67Female40iran
Divya89Female78Dubai
;
run;
```

I want to Separate these 5 variables in 5 observations
Help me on it

Comment: Judging by what you wrote, you have a data with ONE variable, which contains 5 observations. 5 observations that are not separated by any delimiter. Can you fix this issue at input site? It would be easier I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed code that should work for any range of ages/weights. Not the most elegant solution, but it works. But I would still rather fix that at the input site, and put some delimiters into the original string.

```
data want;
    set have;
    mixed2=substr(Mixeddata, anydigit(Mixeddata), anydigit(Mixeddata,-50)-anydigit(Mixeddata)+1);
    mixed3=substr(mixed2, notdigit(mixed2));
    name=substr(Mixeddata,1, anydigit(Mixeddata)-1);
    age=substr(mixed2,1,notdigit(mixed2)-1);
    gender=substr(mixed2, notdigit(mixed2), anydigit(mixed2, 5)-notdigit(mixed2));
    country=substr(Mixeddata, anydigit(Mixeddata, -50)+1);
    weight=substr(mixed3, anydigit(mixed3));
    drop Mixeddata mixed2 mixed3;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the makeup of a single string:

```
Naresh30Male70India
```

Each desired column is either a number or a character. If we could break this out into two strings, one with only numbers and one with only characters, we can easily pull the needed values:

```
string_num:  30 70
string char: Naresh Male India
```

We can do this with regular expressions by replacing letters with spaces and numbers with spaces.

```
data want;
    set have;

    string_num  = compbl(prxchange('s/[0-9]/ /', -1, string) );
    string_char = compbl(prxchange('s/[a-zA-Z]/ /', -1, string) );

    name    = scan(string_num, 1);
    age     = scan(string_char, 1);
    gender  = scan(string_num, 2);
    weight  = scan(string_char, 2);
    country = scan(string_num, 3);

    drop string_num string_char;
run;
```

Note that we use the `compbl` function to remove any extra spaces to make it easier to read for learning purposes, but this is an optional step.